# Remove first array value and insert new item at end

Tags: php, arrays

If I have one variable, for example:

```
$a = 1;
```

I want to insert this value into another array `$b`. If the `$b` array contains <= 5 values, then I want to simply insert the `$a` value at the end of the array, as you would normally do.

But,  if the `$b` array contains more than 5 values, then I need to remove the first element in the array and then insert `$a` value at the end of the array.

How can this be done?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Could you explain?

Comment: @AmalMurali, Seems like he needs `array_shift()` and `array_unshift()`

Comment: @Shankar: Might be. We never know. Voted to close as "Unclear what you're asking". :)

Comment: my question is: if i have one array with 3 elements, if i add new element into that array it will add, but i need  if values exists more than five in array, i want to remove that first element and insert new element at last

Comment: @user3115202: I've updated your question (hopefully) without losing meaning. Is it OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = 3;
$b = array(1,2,3,4,5);

if (count($b) <= 5) { // if $b contains less than or equal to 5 elements
    $b[] = $a;        // add $a to $b
} else {
    array_shift($b);  // remove first element from $b
    $b[] = $a;        // add $a to $b
}

print_r($b);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/81398)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
 $b=array(1,2,3,4,5);
 $newarray = array_slice($b, 1);
 $newarray[]=6;
 print_r($newarray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_shift($b)` will remove and return the first element.

`array_push($b, $value);` or `$b[] = $value;` will add `$value` to the end of the array.

Note, if you plan to access elements other than the first, you may need to say `$b = array_keys($b);` in order to have the array indexes be right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$b=array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b[] = 6;

print_r($b);
?>
```